# C++ multithreading without synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading

C++ : I have 2 threads, each one increments 'n' by doing n++ (n being the global variable) Assuming i am not using any thread synchronization, my requirement is to print 0,1,2,....10.

```
int n = 0 //global variable
```

thread 1:

```
n++;
printf("%d", n);
```

thread 2:

```
n++;
printf("%d", n);
```

Will there be any problem in executing the program without thread synchronization, or it will fulfill my requirement (1,2,3...10).

Comment: Rhetorical question: If concurrently modifying the same variable in two different threads were unproblematic, what would the purpose of thread synchronisation be?

Comment: Even with `std::atomic<int>` (which fixes UB), the display order is not guaranty. As the thread cannot run concurrency, better to use single thread anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard says this program has undefined behaviour, anything can happen. **Anything**, including printing the same number repeatedly, not printing anything, crashing the program, or wiping your hard disk.

1.10 [intro.multithread]

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
>   ...
>   The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

You should use `std::atomic<int>` for a variable concurrently modified by multiple threads, or synchronise with a mutex, to avoid undefined behaviour due to data races.

For your use case you need to ensure that every time the variable is updated you print its value, i.e. *the increment and the print* must happen atomically. Simply updating the integer atomically is not sufficient, you must ensure the result of that increment is printed, rather than printing the value of the variable at some later time (when the other thread might have already changed it, as shown in Rotem's answer).

That could be done like so:

```
std::atomic<int> n{0}; // global variable
```

Thread 1:

```
printf("%d", ++n);
```

Thread 2:

```
printf("%d", ++n);
```

Now every time a thread increments the variable the result of that increment will be passed straight to `printf`.

This assumes that writing to `stdout` is thread-safe and happens in order, to avoid  that assumption use a mutex to create a critical section that updates the variable and prints it, preventing the other thread from either incrementing the variable or printing while the mutex is locked:

```
int n = 0 //global variable
std::mutex mtx; // global mutex
```

Thread 1:

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  ++n;
  printf("%d", n);
}
```

Thread 2:

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  ++n;
  printf("%d", n);
}
```

N.B. there is still no guarantee that the two threads will alternate incrementing and printing, it is entirely possible that the first thread will perform ten increments and print the entire output, without the second thread ever getting a chance to run.

Comment: Without synchronization, using `std::atomic<int>` will not ensure that the prints are correct, only that the incrementation doesn't falter.

Comment: @Rotem Is this the case? Surely if you use std::atomic<int>, which is free from data races, you shouldn't have a problem with the prints?

Comment: @MDavies How so? `std::atomic<int>` can only ever guarantee that the variable is incremented atomically, it's not responsible for what you do with the variable once the incrementation call has returned. Unless you are locking around both the incrementation and the print, the scenario detailed in my answer is still possible and very probable.

Comment: @MDavies You still need to use atomic variables correctly. If you just change the variable in question code to be atomic, anything can happen between increasing the variable, and then getting the value of variable for printing.

Comment: I was under the impression that atomic variables are created in a way to not allow multiple read or writes to happen simultaneously. Thus there should be no overlapping of print functions. I guess you can get the issue of the print reading the variable before it has been incremented?

Comment: @MDavies Even with atomic increments and prints you can get the interleaving "thread A increments; thread B increments; thread A prints; thread B prints;".

Comment: @Rotem, quite right, my original answer only avoided the data race on `n`, it didn't do anything to make the output correct. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

> Will there be any problem in executing the program...

It can happen (and, as Murphy said:
*"if anything can go wrong it will go wrong"*).

#### Rational

Incrementing is *not atomic*, usually it is implemented using the following three basic operations:

1. read the value from memory
2. add 1 to the value
3. write the value back to memory

Note: `printf()` isn't atomic too.

A context switch between threads might occur at any time,
during `n++`, during `printf()` or between those two operations.
A race condition can occur during context switching,
if the access to `n` is not synchronized.

#### Example

Consider the following scenario:

1. thread 1 reads the value (value is 10)
2. thread 2 reads the value (value is 10)
3. thread 1 adds a 1 to the value
4. thread 1 writes the value to memory (value is 11)
5. thread 2 adds a 1 to the value
6. thread 2 writes the value to memory (value is still 11)

You would expect the value to be 12, but it is 11.

#### Conclusion

`n` is a shared resource.

Concurrent (read write) access to shared resources has to be synchronized!

Comment: @nwp All your statements are opinionated and arguable. "A lost update is not a big deal" - to whom and in which context? IMO the two answers you downvoted are important since the top voted answer makes it sounds like using an atomic int would result in correct output.

Comment: @nwp "A lost update is not a big deal" what? it's definitely a bug! And an example for undefined behavior.

Comment: I worded that badly. Sometimes you can live with a lost update, for example if you count function calls to get a feeling for hotspots. My point is that undefined behavior doesn't just produce slightly inaccurate output, it breaks stuff randomly including just crashing, which is a completely different level of bad that in my opinion you should have mentioned.

Comment: @nwp The question is "Will there be any problem ...". This answer answers the question and provides an example. How critical a "lost update" might be is just guessing.

Comment: @nwp, I disagree. There is no 'undefined' behaviour in original example, as defined (pun in inteded) in C++ standard. It is very well defined. It is guaranteed not to crash, not to wipe out your hard disk and not to cause WW3.

Comment: The original example contains a data race and Jonathan Wakely posted the quote from the standard saying that data races are undefined behavior. How is that not undefined behavior then? I think this is the root cause of our disagreement.

Comment: @sergej, I believe, I am a different SergeyA (or you do not have my actual email). Bottom line - I do not have an email from SergeJ

Comment: @nwp, data race is no more undefined behaviour than a call to `do_my_foo()`. It is `undefined` in laymen terms, possibly - since standard does not define what's gonna happen when do_my_foo() is called, one can say `do_my_foo()` is undefined. However, standard actually defines it's undefineds, saying, that 'everything can happen when A is done' (for instance, dereferencing invalid pointer). No such wording exists for data races to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @SergeyA So the yellow text from [Jonathan Wakely's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990225/3484570) is not a standard quote? Or am I just reading it wrong?

Comment: @nwp, I stand corrected! The wording of standard allows compilers to start WW3 when data race is encountered. You won.